# Search Key in Nested json in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to search the key "AylaHeartBeatFrequency" inside nested json. how to search and get its value ? in flutter/dart

```
{
  "sAWSIoT": {
    "CloudStatus": 1,
    "PairingFlag": 0,
  },
  "sDebug": {
    "LocalDebugMsg_d": "Model ID",
    "AylaHeartBeatFrequency": 0
  },
  "Product": {
    "Mode": 1,
    "Model": "abc"
  },
  "data": {
    "DeviceType": 300,
    "Endpoint": 0,
    "UniID": "0000000000000000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not able to understand your question, can you please edit your question and explain it in a better way.

Comment: Which method do you currently use to get the other values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var map = /*put your json here. You can use json.decode() on the json if it's not yet formatted*/, value;
for(var item in map.values) {
  if(item.containsKey('AylaHeartBeatFrequency') {
    value = item['AylaHeartBeatFrequency']) ;
    break;
  }
}
```